# On Kindle 4, can you send a dictionary as email attachment?

Tags: dictionaries

In a Kindle 4, I am trying to install a dictionary between to languages (eg. English->German).

This is what I tried so far:

- I have found a .mobi file from this site http://blog.mikeasoft.com/2011/01/05/free-as-in-gpl2-translation-dictionaries-for-the-kindle/
- I have sent it to my Kindle by email
- The document "German-English" is correctly displayed in the home of my kindle.
- I can also browse it if I open it

But:

- When I go to Settings->Dictionaries I do not find it under the Germans dictionaries.
- When reading a German book, if I put the cursor near a word, I get the definition of the default dictionary (not the transalted one)

So, in a Kindle 4, how can I transfer a dictionary as attachment, so it appears in my list of dictionaries?
(and thus, when reading a document, if I put the cursor in a word, Kindle will use it to translate it)